# Jquery clicking Next and previous for individual containers

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am posting this fiddle again, because I have a new problem with it.

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XvAR6/

Now, I want to add a new container. When I click on the next/previous, only the bottom container's tab should change and this should happen individually for both of them.

I tried this:

html

```
<div class='container1'>

<span class="kunderpagination">
    <a href="#" id="prev">« Previous</a> |
    <a href="#" id="next">Next »</a>
</span>

<ul class="kunder">
    <li>
        <span class="udtalelse">
            <div id="tab1">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#fragment-2"><span>Two</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#fragment-3"><span>Three</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="fragment-1">
                    1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 
                </div>
                <div id="fragment-2">
                2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                </div>
                <div id="fragment-3">
                3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                </div>
             </div>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="udtalelse">
                <div id="tab2">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#fragment-4"><span>Four</span></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#fragment-5"><span>Five</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#fragment-6"><span>Six</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="fragment-4">
                    4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat
                </div>
                <div id="fragment-5">
                5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                </div>
                <div id="fragment-6">
                6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                </div>
             </div>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="udtalelse">
            3
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>

<div class='container2'>

<span class="kunderpagination2">
    <a href="#" id="prev">« Previous</a> |
    <a href="#" id="next">Next »</a>
</span>

<ul class="kunder2">
    <li>
        <span class="udtalelse">
            <div id="tab3">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#fragment-7"><span>One</span></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#fragment-8"><span>Two</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#fragment-9"><span>Three</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="fragment-7">
                    1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 
                </div>
                <div id="fragment-8">
                2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                </div>
                <div id="fragment-9">
                3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                </div>
             </div>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="udtalelse">
                <div id="tab4">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#fragment-10"><span>Four</span></a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#fragment-11"><span>Five</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#fragment-12"><span>Six</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="fragment-10">
                    4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 
                </div>
                <div id="fragment-11">
                5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                </div>
                <div id="fragment-12">
                6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
                </div>
             </div>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="udtalelse">
            3
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

and jquery:

```
$("#tab1, #tab2, #tab3, #tab4").tabs({active: 1}).tabs({
        collapsible: false,
        hide: {
            effect: "slideUp",
            duration: 500
        },
        show: {
            effect: "slideDown",
            duration: 500
        }
    });

var all = $('.udtalelse').addClass("passiv");

var i = -1;

$('#prev').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    ctrlKunder( i = !i ? all.length - 1 : --i );
});
$('#next').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    ctrlKunder( i = ++i % all.length );
}).click();

function ctrlKunder(ele) {
    all.removeClass("active").addClass("passiv");
    all.eq(ele).removeClass("passiv").addClass("active");
}
```

Can somebody please tell me what is wrong in my code and why the second one is not working

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you must use unique IDs on elements. The solution is to change the buttons from using id to class in both kunderpagination and kunderpagination2. And optionally, you should probably change kunderpagination and kunderpagination2 to use IDs instead of classes, but that's just a suggestion since that's not causing any problems.

Change both occurrences of this:

```
<a href="#" id="prev">« Previous</a> |
<a href="#" id="next">Next »</a>
```

to this:

```
<a href="#" class="prev">« Previous</a> |
<a href="#" class="next">Next »</a>
```

1. And update the jquery code to select the class, not the IDs.

change this:

```
$('#prev').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    ctrlKunder( i = !i ? all.length - 1 : --i );
});

$('#next').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    ctrlKunder( i = ++i % all.length );
}).click();
```

to this:

```
$('.prev').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    ctrlKunder( i = !i ? all.length - 1 : --i );
});
$('.next').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    ctrlKunder( i = ++i % all.length );
}).click();
```

Your new working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/acturbo/xNFgs/

Comment: No this is not working, where is `.container2` div ? it should be shown same as `container1` div, just bellow the `kunderpagination` div indevidually.

Comment: See it now.
[http://jsfiddle.net/asif097/xNFgs/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/asif097/xNFgs/1/)